# Querying text strings with sql - how to look for sequences of words by category

Tags: sql, join, self-join

Fairly new to SQL and am tying myself in knots over over a query.

I am querying text strings looking for combinations / sequences of words which are stored according to categories (let's say noun, verb, adjective).

In this query, I am looking for a sequence where a verb directly follows a noun.

The table I am querying is structured:

```
article_index
text
word_type (noun, verb etc)
word
```

I need to write a query eg

```
text like '% '+ [word, word_type is noun] + ' ' + [word, word_type is verb] + ' %'
```

so it would pick up "the **duck flew** overhead".

How do I include the reference to the `word_type` column?

Sample data:

```
article_index   text                           word_type    word
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1            ...the duck flew overhead...   noun         duck 
   1            ...the duck flew overhead...   verb         flew
   1            ...the duck flew overhead...   adjective    overhead
```

Desired result:

```
article_index   text                             noun_verb_sequence
--------------------------------------------------------------------
     1          ...the duck flew overhead...     duck flew
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag woul all help.

Comment: Sorry Gordon - new here - I'll amend the post above.

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want to know if two words are next to each other, you need the positions of those words in each article.

Comment: Actually I think I've cracked it... I did need to do a self join.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

`select ta1.article_key, ta1.text, ta1.word as noun, ta2.word as verb, concat (ta1.noun,' ', ta2.verb) as noun_verb`

`from table_name as ta1, table_name as ta2`

`where var1.text like '% ' + ta1.word + ' ' + ta2.word + ' %' and (ta1.word_type="noun" and ta2.word_type='verb' and ta1.article_key=ta2.article_key)`

`order by article_key`

Is there an obvious flaw there that might bite me when I scale up the dataset?

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Also re line breaks. Ask questions in question posts, not comments. If this is a modification of your question, edit your question, don't make a new answer or question post. But don't edit a question to invalidate reasonable posted answers. Don't post code-only answers, explain how/why the code is an answer to the problem/question.